# Where to store persistent player data?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm working on a 2d game, where the player can take damage and die. And upon death, player object gets destroyed.

However, some attributes of player shouldn't be affected by his death, such as lives, ammo, current weapon and so on. I'm wondering where to store these values.

I'm using c++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you destroy the player class, if you clearly want to preserve data related to that player.

Instead of destroying the player class use a statemachine to tell what state the player is in (alive, dead) and add a state if the player has run out of lives to signal the end of the game.

Keep the data close to the object 'owning' the data. Imagine you make your game multiplayer, it is easier to keep track of this data in the player objects than to design a storage that scales whith the number of players or keeps track what property belonged to what player.